# Define the custom function on-the-fly without defining explicitly

Tags: python

I have below code

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
def process(i):
    return i * i
    
results = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(process)(i) for i in range(10))
```

I am wondering if instead of explicitly defining my function process if I can define the function on-the-fly within `Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(<<here ??>>)(i) for i in range(10))`?

In this example, my function `process` is one-liner and pretty simple. However actually I have a more complex function and I want to define within `Parallel` function (not explicitly).

One such example of my custom function may be

```
def process(i):
    def process_1(j) :
      return i - j + 12 if j > 100 else i + j
    if i > 123 :
      k = process_1(i)
    else :
      k = process_1(i - 23)
    return k * i
```

Comment: Would a lambda expression suite your need? E.g. `Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(lambda arg: arg * arg)(i) for i in range(10))`

Comment: @FanchenBao Thanks. But in my actual function I have codes which spread across more than one line. How can I write a `lambda` function for such case?

Comment: You forgot to show that actual function.

Comment: @BrianSmith see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862412/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-statements-in-a-python-lambda-expression

Comment: What do you mean by "explicitly"? There's no way to implicitly define a function as far as I understand the word. Maybe you're looking for a partial or a closure, which would, basically, set up functionality on the fly but not involve a definition.

Comment: The only kind of function definition that can be written in the middle of an expression is a lambda - and lambdas are limited to a single expression, which is implicitly `return`ed.  You have no choice but to use a separate `def` for anything more complicated than that.

Comment: @KellyBundy I have updated my original post with an example of my multi-liner function

Comment: @jasonharper I have updated my post with an example of my function. Is it possible to convert my example function to `lambda` expression?

Comment: In this example it seems to be possible.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I really need some insight on how? I want to keep basic structure of my custom function asis (e.g. defining another function within my function etc)

Comment: Just write a horribly complicated and unreadable expression that is equivalent to the return value of your current `process` function. Something like `lambda i: (process_1(i - 23) if i > 123 else process_1(i)) * i` where you substitute the body of `process_1` two times.

Comment: "Explicit is better than implicit." --[The Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python) Just `def` it.

Comment: If the determination of which function to run should occur before calling Parallel, then it should just be a dict lookup or call another function which returns the function to be delayed.  If the determination will occur at the time the delayed function executes, then its as simplr as having that function call to the desired code to execute and return its result.

Answer (score 0):

For fun and to see just how unreadable it becomes. I'll transform it in several steps:

```
def process(i):
    def process_1(j) :
      return i - j + 12 if j > 100 else i + j
    if i > 123 :
      k = process_1(i)
    else :
      k = process_1(i - 23)
    return k * i
```

```
def process(i):
    def process_1(j) :
      return i - j + 12 if j > 100 else i + j
    k = process_1(i if i > 123 else i - 23)
    return k * i
```

```
def process(i):
    def process_1(j) :
      return i - j + 12 if j > 100 else i + j
    return process_1(i if i > 123 else i - 23) * i
```

```
def process(i):
    process_1 = lambda j: i - j + 12 if j > 100 else i + j
    return process_1(i if i > 123 else i - 23) * i
```

```
def process(i):
    return (lambda j: i - j + 12 if j > 100 else i + j)(i if i > 123 else i - 23) * i
```

```
process = lambda i: (lambda j: i - j + 12 if j > 100 else i + j)(i if i > 123 else i - 23) * i
```

And now you can dump that into your statement

```
results = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(process)(i) for i in range(10))
```

by replacing `process` there:

```
results = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(lambda i: (lambda j: i - j + 12 if j > 100 else i + j)(i if i > 123 else i - 23) * i)(i) for i in range(10))
```

What's not to love about that?